# How do I start the crossbow challenge?

Tags: dragon-quest-xi

How do I start the crossbow challenge in *Dragon Quest XI S*? I’ve spoken to Bo in Gallopolis, but he hasn’t mentioned the challenge yet to me. Do I have to find a bodkin at a campsite first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crossbow sidequest/minigame has been removed from the Switch edition of Dragon Quest 11.

Answer (score 1):

From my play through last year on the PS4, I vaguely remember that you have to finish the story content in Gallopolis before you can start the crossbow challenge.  If you've already finished it, you can pop over to the campsite southwest of Gallopolis and talk to the Bodkin there to see if that will fix your issue.  I cannot give you a 100% proven answer since I had already talked to a Bodkin before talking to Bo and all guides online just say to talk to him.

What I can say for certain is you need to finish up the story content in Gallopolis (in part 1) before you can start the crossbow challenge.

Comment: What time of day is the bodkin there?

Comment: I believe they are there at any time of day.  He is near the bell to call your horse from the looks of it on this map.  https://www.hardcoregamer.com/2018/09/03/dragon-quest-xi-crossbow-target-guide/309712/
If you want to find all the targets yourself don't check the link since it is a guide to where all targets/bodkin archers are.